# Proving $x^x+y^y\ge\sqrt2$ when $x,y\in \mathbb R^+$ and $x+y=1$

Tags: analysis, inequality

Assuming  $x,y\in \mathbb R^+$,  $x+y=1$ how to prove $$x^x+y^y\ge\sqrt2$$thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried using $x\mapsto x^x+(1-x)^{1-x}$?

Comment: +1 nice question. What do you think about the proof?

Comment: i use AM_GM inequality but it doesn't help until now

Comment: However, it would be interesting to get an elementary solution based on AM-GM inequality...

Comment: @Chriss-sister:$x^x+y^y\ge2\sqrt{x^xy^y}$ then how  complete it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's consider the function
$$f(x)=x \ln x +(1-x)\ln(1-x)$$
where $0<x<1$, and then
$$f'(x)=\ln\frac{x}{1-x}$$
$$f'\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=0$$
where $x_0=\frac{1}{2}$ is the point where the function reaches its minimum. Then
$$f(x)\ge f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$$ 
that finally yields
$$x \ln x +y \ln y \ge \ln\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\tag1$$ 
Now, let's rewrite the left side inequality, use AM-GM inequality and then use $(1)$ 
$$e^{x \ln x}+e^{y\ln y}\ge 2 {\displaystyle e^{\displaystyle\frac{x \ln x+y \ln y}{2}}}\ge2 {\displaystyle e^{\displaystyle\frac{\ln(1/2)}{2}}}=\sqrt{2}$$

Chris.

Comment: The AM-GM can be proven with Jensen, but this definitely a different approach. (+1)

Comment: @robjohn: thanks! When I realized that I need to use the derivatives, I tried to make things as easy as possible. This is what I got. :-)

Answer (score 5):

Without Jensen:
Lets minimize the function on in the positive quadrant.
\begin{align}
f(x)&=x^x+(1-x)^{(1-x)}\\
f^\prime(x)&=(1-x)^{(-x)} (-1+x) (1+\log(1-x))+x^x (1+\log(x))
\end{align}
Equating to zero and solving. (You can also verify that the second derivative is positive)
\begin{align}
x&=0.5\\
f(x)&=(0.5)^{0.5}+(0.5)^{0.5}\\
f(x)&=2\times (0.5)^{0.5}\\
f(x)&=(4\times 0.5)^{0.5}\\
f(x)&=\sqrt{2}\\
\therefore~~~~~~ f(x)&\geq \sqrt{2}\quad \forall x\in \mathbb{R}^+
\end{align}

Comment: Brute force works, too (+1)

Answer (score 3):

**HINT** Prove that $x^x$ is convex in the interval $[0,1]$. Then use [Jensen's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality).

Comment: Jensen is quite useful (+1)

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Apply Jensen's Inequality on $f(x)=x^x$.

Comment: Jensen is quite useful (+1) (Marvis beat you by a couple of minutes)

Comment: I know. I was working it out while typing out the answer and didn't realize it. Chris' sisters' method is more elegant though(in my opinion).

Comment: Chris's sister's answer is nice, but when I saw the question, Jensen was the first thing that came to my mind.